# When an applicant submits Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization), in what case(s) does the USCIS reuse previously submitted biometrics?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I [read](https://lneedle.com/navigating-the-biometrics-process/#:%7E:text=USCIS%20is%20authorized%20to%20reuse,identity%20and%20perform%20security%20checks.):

> USCIS is authorized to reuse previously submitted biometrics under limited circumstances to verify an individual's identity and perform security checks.

When an applicant submit Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization), in what case(s) does the USCIS reuse previously submitted biometrics?

---

Example of biometrics reuse notice:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The [USCIS will reuse](https://content.govdelivery.com/attachments/USDHSCISINVITE/2020/03/30/file_attachments/1414523/COVID-19%20Biometrics%20Reuse%2003-30-2020.pdf?ct=t(AgencyUpdate_033120)) your biometrics if you have reusable biometrics from a prior application, your biometrics appointment was scheduled to after March 18th 2020, and the ASC where it was scheduled had not resumed its normal operations which were disrupted due to the COVID pandemic.

The announcement is with regards to EAD applications, the USCIS made no such announcement with regards to N400. That doesn't mean that they do not "silently" reuse biometrics for N400, but it does mean that you cannot rely on anecdotal evidence you've found elsewhere as a guidance to yourself.

The link is to the **official** USCIS announcement. I do not consider random people on the internet to be a reliable source or anecdotal data to be a reliable evidence, so unless told otherwise by the USCIS, expect to be required to show up at an ASC for a biometrics appointment.

Comment: Your link says "U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services today announced that it will reuse previously 
submitted biometrics in order to process valid Form I-765, Application for Employment 
Authorization, extension requests due to the temporary closure of Application Support Centers
(ASC) to the public in response to the Coronavirus (COVID-19) pandemic." Doesn't mention naturalization.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, That's the only **official** announcement the USCIS made on the matter. In any case, ASCs are now open, so the issue is moot.

Comment: "ASCs are now open, so the issue is moot" -> does it mean biometrics aren't reused anymore for naturalization applicants?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt as I said, that was the only update the USCIS has provided. It is safe to assume that unless they *have to* reuse, they will not.

Comment: If re-using worked fine during covid, why do you assume they'll stop re-using?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt because pre-covid that was the behavior and I have no reason to assume that the government would relax the requirements unless absolutely has to. Regardless, my assumptions and your insistence on them is irrelevant. I provided you the source, you have further questions - address the source. I know you like to troll, so I'll disengage now. Good luck with your application.

Comment: Your source doesn't pertain to naturalization, and is out-of-date since ASCs reopened.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt so is yours. Your source link and example are from the pandemic period when ASCs were closed.